# Pass custom parameters in laravel 5.4 validation

Tags: laravel, csv, validation, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

I am developing an application in laravel 5.4 and vuejs (multi lang support), which validate the content of a csv file. I have parsed csv file using vuejs and result json array post to Laravel.

On Laravel I looped the json array and validate the field using laravel validator.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($json_array as $key => $value) {

   $params contains employee_id's and employee_name's

   $i = $i + 1;       

   Validator::make($params, [
            'employee_id'         => 'required|integer|exists:employees,employee_id',
            'employee_name'       => 'required|string',     
        ])->validate();
}
```

This is possible using laravel validation and laravel trigger error if any breaks in validation rule.

example: Laravel show error "employee_name is required" if the csv file have an empty field of employee_name.

Now I need to show error with line number (row), Line number can get using $i variable. How can I pass the $i variable (row) to validation file to show my error with line number.

I already spented lot of time to pass variable as parameter to validation message(on validation file). But i did'nt get a solution.

Output i expect is :

Example :

"employee_name is required in line : 8" if the csv file have an empty field of employee_name on line 8.

Also how can I get col number when an error is triggered?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Your need is not possibile to solve with existing validation rules, my advice is to use a custom validation rule, but yo have to try by yourself, you can read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: Send message array to the make method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel validator allows for custom messages to be passed as a third parameter, try this out

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($json_array as $key => $value) {
    $i++;
    $messages = [
      'required' => str_replace(":line",$i,trans('validation.required')),
    ];
    Validator::make($params, [
        'employee_id'         => 'required|integer|exists:employees,employee_id',
        'employee_name'       => 'required|string',     
    ],$messages)->validate();
}

// .project/resources/lang/en/validation.php
'required' => 'The :attribute is required in the line :line.',
```

Comment: I have already tried that, this will work. But I am developing a multi lang support application so I need the parameter( $i -row count) in lang file. Also how can I get col number when an error is triggered.

Comment: I belive you can get the column with the `$key` variable, check it out. also i've updated my answer, regarding the multi lang support.